# django URL in a TextField with HTML

Tags: django, templates, url, href

In my Django e-commerce project, I have an obvious Product model with an expected *description* field:

> description = models.TextField(...)

I have the following url configured:

> path("product/slug:slug", views.product_detail,
> name="product_detail"),

which, obviously, serves URLs like this:

> http://localhost:8000/product/foo

and when a product **foo** is a part of a set with product **bar**, I want to add respective links to the description field on such products, like "you might want to buy ***bar*** together with this".

However, adding a link to **bar** to the *description* of **foo** proved tricky.
The whole description field (imported from a legacy ecomm app) can contain arbitrary HTML, and since it's not a user input, I render it like this in the template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
  {{ product.description }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

When I add this to the (TextField) description:

```
> This item together with <a href="product/bar">Bar</a> (sold separately)
```

, the URL produced in the template is wrong:

http://localhost:8000/product/product/bar/

, but if I *don't* use this '/product' in the description's url:

```
> This item together with <a href="/bar">Bar</a> (sold separately)
```

, the URL is also wrong:

> http://localhost:8000/bar/

I'll admit, I don't understand how Django constructed the first *or* second URL. So it's ironic that neither is what I want )

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to Django.
Try to use

```
    > This item together with <a href="/product/bar">Bar</a> (sold separately)
```

Notice the link starts with a slash

Hope it helps

Comment: Also notice that your URL definition should probably be :  path("product/<slug:slug>", views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),

Comment: thanks a bunch! I kinda knew it's not Django, since template rendering is not even a part of a picture here (except for turning off the autoescape). as for the URL, I blame SO markup, didn't notice it stole my angular brackets =)